# android onclicklistener GUI change

Tags: java, android

I am having a silly issue with onClickListeners modifying GUI elements.  Below I have a radioGroup holding two buttons, an EditText and a Spinner.  When the choose_old radio button is selected, I simply wanted to toggle enable/disable between the Spinner and EditText.  The variables select_run and new_run_name are both instance variables and are
obtained from my XML files.

```
select_run = (Spinner)runDialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.run_choice_spinner);
new_run_name = (EditText)runDialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.new_run_name);
RadioButton choose_old = (RadioButton)runDialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.select_old);
RadioButton choose_new = (RadioButton)runDialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.select_new);

choose_old.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
     Log.e("ERROR","GOT CLICK");
     select_run.setEnabled(true);
     new_run_name.setEnabled(false);        
   }
});
```

The 'GOT CLICK' message prints but I do not get the desired changes.

Note:

1. In trying solutions, I had wrapped the GUI changes in a handler.post with no effect.
2. If I set to enabled outside the onClickListener, it successfully changes it.

I've no doubt this is something dumb but can't seem to figure out why this is happening

Comment: The code you have supplied works fine for me too. It must be somewhere else, that you override the state of the spinner and the edittext. What does your xml file look like? And what about the rest of your activity? The code you've supplied are called in the onCreate method right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this code in the listener.

```
 boolean b = select_run.isEnabled();
 select_run.setEnabled(!b);
 new_run_name.setEnabled(b);
```

Comment: Interesting, this works.  I'm rather confused at why this is.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code seems to work fine for me, please make sure views accessed in onClick are declared final

```
    final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    final EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setText("Hi There");

    RelativeLayout vg = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, button2.getId());
    vg.addView(et, lp);


    final RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF ,button2.getId());
    vg.addView(rb, lp1);
    rb.setSelected(false);
    rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to declare the views, that you manipulate inside the OnClickListener, final.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  @Darwind that brings an interesting point.  Would you be able to tell me as succinctly as possible why locally scoped variables must be final in onClick() and object scoped variables do not?

Comment: @agent0range You got me there ;) Had to do a little digging to find an appropriate short answer ;) The short answer is this: 
"The rule is anonymous inner classes may only access final local variables of the enclosing method. Why? Because the inner class’s methods may be invoked later, long after the method that spawned it has terminated". 
Global variables will live longer. As we know, "final" variables can't be changed after they've been set the first time.
I couldn't find a short answer myself, so this is pasted from http://mindprod.com/jgloss/nestedclasses.html - hope this helps ;-)